# Edit tags of deleted question

Tags: bug, tagging, editing, 10k-tools

It's possible to edit tags of deleted questions. I tried it here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835159/math-expectation-playing-a-game
 My new tag was accepted although the question is deleted.

Is this a bug?

At first glance it also seemed possible to cast another close vote, but finally the system realized that the question is already deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can edit deleted posts; [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225235/214632) describes the situations in which a user is able to edit a deleted post (basically if the user can see the deleted post, and the post is not a question which the user was the author of and self-deleted, then the user can edit it).

Comment: However, since I (in my capacity as a ♦-moderator) was the one who (unilaterally, mind you) deleted that non-question, you (and every other non-♦-moderator) will have difficulty undeleting it.